# How to correctly handle encoding in scraping a site

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, screen-scraping

I am quite a newbie in coding but i am trying to learn to use Python for web scraping.
At this time I am trying to extract the price of a product from this code:

```
<div class="a-column a-span2 a-text-right sc-item-right-col a-span-last">
   <p class="a-spacing-mini">
    <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base sc-product-price a-text-bold">
        1 089,70&nbsp;€
    </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

using this code:

```
def get_amazon_price(dom):
    item_price = dom.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base sc-product-price a-text-bold"]/text()')[0]
    print(item_price)
    item_price = item_price.replace('€', '').replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
    item_price = int(item_price)/100
    print(item_price)
    return item_price
```

The issue is that running the code several times doesn't give me the same result (sometimes i get the correct price 1089,70 and sometimes i get no price value).
I think this can be something related to encoding, can you help me?
Thanks a lot.

I am trying to extract a price from a web page but doing that gives different result. I think this can be related to encoding.

Comment: Why do you think it's related to encoding? Are you getting any errors? If so, please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Log response to a file and analyze it. Scrapping isn't a legal action, so many websites are protecting themself and may return corrupted data.

Comment: @Green_Wizard You say, "Scraping isn't a legal action." That is a blanket statement. Where is it not legal and what type of data are you referring to? Everywhere?  Any and all data? See [this](https://techcrunch.com/2022/04/18/web-scraping-legal-court/) and [this](https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/is-web-scraping-legal/), so please cite your sources because I don't know what to believe now and would like to know where and when it is not legal. **"All I know is what I read in the papers, and that's an alibi for my ignorance." - Will Rogers**

Comment: I wrote responses to a .txt file and got this:


[<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>][<Response [503]>][<Response [200]>]

Seems that sometimes i get errore 503 so probably the site is blocking me from scraping?

Comment: @Michelino yes, or some issues with servers. Try to add some delays between requests, it may help in the easiest case.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try :) thanks everyone for your help!